# How to Uninstall Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am facing fatal errors regarding Artisan. I think I couldn't install laravel complete due to slow internet. Now I want to remove Laravel from root and want to have fresh installation.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Delete the `vendor` directory and then run `composer install`. However artisan fatal errors are not always caused by laravel itself but by your own app's code so it would be useful to provide more detail.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

if you have installed it globally you can simply remove it by `composer global remove laravel/installer`

If you have installed it via composer project you simply remove the directory.

Comment: For me, the command that actually did the trick was: `composer global remove laravel/installer`.

Comment: For me, the command that actually did the trick was: `composer global remove laravel/installer`

Answer (score 2):

Since I was looking all around how to uninstall packages and after reading tones 
of documentations here's the short how-to uninstall a workbench package in Laravel

1. Remove package service provider from 'providers' array in app/config/app.php
2. Remove the package folder in workbench/
3. Run:

   php composer.phar dump-autoload

   php artisan clear-compiled

   php artisan optimize
4. (optional) remove all related code using the package (you'll get errors about that)

or use `composer global remove laravel/installer`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the command that actually did the trick was: `composer global remove laravel/installer`