# make:resource and make:factory command cannot be found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create an [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) in Laravel 5.4 and also 5.6 and by some reason when I create type the `make:resource` command, it says **cannot be found**. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. And the make:factory as well cannot be found

this is the command i run

> Felix@DESKTOP-O26O7PO MINGW64 /c/wamp/www/larticles
>   $ php artisan make:resource exampleresource
>
> > Command **make:resource** is
> >       not defined.

Comment: You have told us nothing with your post. You need to provide code samples and specific outputs of errors.

Comment: Its an error on the CLI which says 
  Command "make:resource" is
  not defined.

Comment: Perform a `php artisan list`, which will prompt all the available artisan commands. Tell us (preferably written in your topic to inform folks) what you have around `make` commands.

Comment: `php artisan list` gives me all the list of commands excluding the ones I stated in my question.

Comment: What I did was to upgrade to laravel 5.5 and php to version 7.1.16 because laravel >= 5.5 requires php >=7 to run and after that, I run composer update to update my settings and it worked perfectly after running php artisan list. I can now run the make:resource and make:factory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I did was to upgrade to laravel 5.5 and php to version 7.1.16 because `laravel >= 5.5` requires `php >=7` to run and after that, I run `composer update` to update my settings and it worked perfectly after running `php artisan list`. I can now run the `make:resource` and `make:factory`. Thanks for the contributions.

Comment: hi, it would be really helpful if you would add more details to how you did this?

Comment: Are you having the same issue?

Comment: yeah, but i found a solution. i've also it documented above

Answer (score 1):

Seems that make:resource is not available in 5.4, also when changing laravel to new version, you should use `composer update` after changing the specified version to update your autoload scripts.

Comment: Yeah I  actually upgraded to `laravel 5.5` and php to version `7.1.16` because `laravel >= 5.5` requires `php >=7` to run and after that, I run `composer update` to update my settings and it worked perfectly after running `php artisan list`. I can now run the `make:resource` and `make:factory`.

Answer (score 1):

on Laravel 5.2> version we use factory in ModelFactory file for example

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

$factory->define(App\Article::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

static $password; //this is default created

return [ 'name' => $faker->name, 'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail, 'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'), 'remember_token' => str_random(10), ];

});
```

the second creatin in below

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

$factory->define(App\Model::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

return [ 'title' => $faker->text(50), 'body' => $faker->text(250) ];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to run `php artisan make:factory ArticleFactory` but it didn't work.

This is everything I had to do to resolve it:

### update php to 7+

0) Run `php --version` on CLI to determine what version your composer is running. If it's not 7+, then do following:

1) Uninstall composer

2) Install composer → select the path environment variable of 7+

### update laravel to 5.5+

1) Run `php artisan --version` to see which version you are on. Mine was at `5.4`

2) Go to `composer.json` and edit the `"laravel/framework"` to `"5.5.*"`

---

Rerun command. Should work now

this is on a windows 10 PC so your results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue

turns out I was using an older version of `laravel 2.x`

```
# reinstall `laravel` using `composer`

composer global remove laravel/installer
composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0"
```

this didn't work for me, because I had `php 5.5` and `laravel 4.0` requires `php 7.x`

> ```
> # update `php` using `brew`  
> brew upgrade php
> ```
>
> ```
> # or
> brew install php@7.1
> ```
>
> didn't work for me, because i was using an older unsupported mac `osx 10.11`
>
> > ```
> > # download `php` with third-party support
> > curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
> >
> > # add `php` to path 
> > echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:${PATH}"' >> .bash_profile
> > ```

```
# reinstall composer

rm /usr/local/bin/composer

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

```
# reinstall `laravel` with `composer`

composer global remove laravel/installer
composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

## refrences

[How to Uninstall Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397433/how-to-uninstall-laravel/45397723)
[Package laravel/ui at version has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.6.40)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361906/package-laravel-ui-at-version-has-a-php-requirement-incompatible-with-your-php-v)
[Install PHP 7.3 for Mac WITHOUT HomeBrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087400/install-php-7-3-for-mac-without-homebrew)
[Remove composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396451/remove-composer)