# Install PHP 7.3 for Mac WITHOUT HomeBrew

Tags: php, macos, installation

been struggling to figure out why my install of php 7.3 is not being recognized.

I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

I get a success message, but then when I try to verify the version, it says **PHP 7.1**.

I have updated my **.bash_profile** with the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Even after updating the path, I still get **PHP 7.1** when I run php -v.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace "php5" with "php7" or "php" from your `PATH`

Remember to open new bash session (or source your profile `source .bash_profile`) after you changed PATH value from your **.bash_profile**