# Package laravel/ui at version has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.6.40)

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is when I want to run command : `composer require laravel/ui --dev` 
i get an error with title :  `[InvalidArgumentException]` 
and error message is :

> Package laravel/ui at version  has a PHP requirement incompatible
>   with your PHP version (5.6.40)
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--]
>   []...`

**NOTE** : My PHP Version is : `7.4.3`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that the composer is using an old PHP version on your system, try to reconfigure it using this command:

```
composer config platform.php 7.4.3
```

Answer (score 14):

I had this error with some other package installations on my local version (my local php version differed from the one on server) so I just ran:

```
composer require "some/other-package:^1.0" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

and all is fine now.

Comment: Never ignore platform requirements unless you really know what you are doing. Platform constraints are there for a reason. This is not a fix. It’s a workaround with possible side effects of the required library not working properly. You are supposed to fix your environment - not to suppress errors.

Comment: @emix sure! you are right. this was for the time I didn't use docker for my deployment and environment settings and didn't want to change my local settings. If someone uses this, they must make sure all will be fine on their main deployment.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes due to compatible version in your `composer.json` file. To permanently fix this issue, change the `composer.json` file "`platform`" configuration:

```
"platform": {
            "php": "7.4.3"
 }
```

Then execute `composer install`

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Dec**

if being supposed  to install **"laravel/ui"**
naturally it would claim for matching  php version because current **ui** level is **3.3.0** and  php's is **8.0.2** (or so, not sure). Thus what you re going to console next is:

```
composer update      //in case you corrupted something 
composer require laravel/ui:^3.3.0
```